# Facebook: Off-site comments restricted for new members?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I'm implementing a Facebook comment box on my website. It works for the most part. However, the two comments I made in the comment box do not show up on any computer except the one where I'm signed in to Facebook. But an associate has posted three comments, and hers have shown up just fine, so I know the box is connecting to Facebook and working.

Here's the thing: I am a new Facebook member (joined a month ago). I only joined for the purposes of this project. I have no friends on the site. So I am wondering if this is why my comments do not show. There is online speculation about this, but nothing conclusive or solutions.

My first comment does not even show up in my FB activity monitor. It was made while my post visibility was set to "only me." I did not tick the "also post to Facebook" box for this comment.

The second comment I made does show up in my FB activity monitor and is set to Public. This comment was made after I switched my post visibility to "friends" and ticked the "also post to Facebook" box. But it still does not show up in the comment box on the website, even though Facebook obviously knows it's there, since my activity monitor shows the URL of my website page.

My associate has been a member of Facebook for years and has tons of FB friends. So I am wondering if Facebook has a filter that catches new members like me who have no friends and begin to post comments. Note, however, that I have not posted comments anywhere else online so I can't imagine why a spam filter would be triggered aside from my newbie status. All I can figure is that Facebook doesn't let a new member's comments show off-site until they reach...what? A certain magic number of friends?

Here is the test page with the comment box. It is a Fancybox gallery in which the comment box is attached to the full-size image. Click on the thumbnail, and you will see the comment box attached to the full-size image. You will likely see the three comments from my associate (the singer, FYI--please refrain from posting her name for her privacy).
http://www.lycochoir.com/new/tattoo/thumbnails-comments.html

Do any experienced Facebook developers know anything about this phenomenon that might help me? I can't develop a comment box that I can't use myself, but there's no way to know how much Facebook activity is required to enable my comments to show up. And since the comment moderation feature is not working either, I don't know if the two issues are connected.

Answer (score 0):

In case any other developer is asking this same question, I may have found the answer. The USA Today site says that in order for Facebook comments to be visible on their site, the user must have a profile photo and at least four friends. Their Q&A is almost two years old, so that could have changed, but that is the only hard information I've found on this topic online.